# Bessel functions - seeking funny analogies for students

Tags: education, bessel-functions

Suppose you were a teacher and you were teaching your students about solutions to the wave equations in the spherical coordinates system. After showing them the method of separation of variables, you arrive at the Bessel functions $J_m(z)$ and $Y_m(z)$ which come out to be part of the solution you are seeking for. You then show them the graph of these functions for, let's say $m=0,1,2,3$.

Your goal as a teacher is that your students remember the main properties (value at 0 and $\infty$ and overall shape) of these functions and are able to sketch them.

**What funny analogies can you find in order for these graphs to stick in their head?** Maybe $J$ and $Y$ are the first letter of some word and the overall shape of these functions tells a story over time...

Comment: Do you strictly need a story to tell that $J_0(x)$ is an entire function, whose zeroes on the real axis behave like the zeroes of $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ and whose decay at $|x|\to +\infty$ is of the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$ kind? There are insightful mathematical explanations of this phenomena which are more effective (with a greater chance to *stick*) than simply sketching or telling the graph through a story. But, of course, this is just my opinion.

Comment: Have you already told them that Bessel functions allow us to [*hear the shape of a drum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_the_shape_of_a_drum)? Welcome to MSE, by the way.